# Как вывести "status": "member" из bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=message.chat.id, user_id=message.from_user.id)

Tags: python, aiogram

Добрый день или вечер гуру по питону. Как вывести "status": "member" из bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=message.chat.id, user_id=message.from_user.id)
Сам код:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def bot_message(message: types.Message):
test1 = ['creator', 'administrator', 'member']
user_status = bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=message.chat.id, user_id=message.from_user.id)
if message.text == 'СЫЛЛКА НА ПРИВАТНЫЙ КАНАЛ':
            if db.get_sub_status(message.from_user.id):
                if user_status in test1:
                    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Вы уже находитесь в канале!")
                else:
                    expire_date = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)
                    link = await bot.create_chat_invite_link(chat_id, expire_date, 1)
                    await message.reply(link.invite_link, parse_mode="HTML")
                    user_channel_status = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=chat_id, user_id=message.chat.id)
                    print(user_channel_status)
            else:
                await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Купи подписку")
```

Пытался сделать обычную проверку, есть ли пользователь в канале. Если есть какой-то другой способ использовать проверку, то пожалуйста комментируйте.
Пытался вывести данную вручную, но увы не получилось.

```
str(bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=message.chat.id,user_id=message.from_user.id).status)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, Вы забыли `await` перед вызовом асинхронной функции:

```py
user_status = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=message.chat.id, user_id=message.from_user.id)
```

Во-вторых, если Вы откроете в документации метод [getChatMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember), то увидите, что эта функция возвращает объект `ChatMember`.

В-третьих, если посмотрите в документации, что это за объект такой, [ChatMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmember), то узнаете, что есть несколько типов, а именно:

> This object contains information about one member of a chat.
> Currently, the following 6 types of chat members are supported:
>
> - ChatMemberOwner
> - ChatMemberAdministrator
> - ChatMemberMember
> - ChatMemberRestricted
> - ChatMemberLeft
> - ChatMemberBanned

В таком случае, Вам нужно проверять является ли Ваш `user_status` объектом `ChatMemberMember`:

```py
if isinstance(user_status, ChatMemberMember):
    # Пользователь является участником чата
```

В итоге всё будет выглядеть примерно так:

```py
@dp.message_handler()
async def bot_message(message: types.Message):
user_status = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=message.chat.id, user_id=message.from_user.id)
if message.text == 'СЫЛЛКА НА ПРИВАТНЫЙ КАНАЛ':
            if db.get_sub_status(message.from_user.id):
                if isinstance(user_status, ChatMemberMember)
                    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Вы уже находитесь в канале!")
                else:
                    expire_date = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)
                    link = await bot.create_chat_invite_link(chat_id, expire_date, 1)
                    await message.reply(link.invite_link, parse_mode="HTML")
                    user_channel_status = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=chat_id, user_id=message.chat.id)
                    print(user_channel_status)
            else:
                await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Купи подписку")
```

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку. 
if isinstance(user_status, ChatMemberMember):
NameError: name 'ChatMemberMember' is not defined

Comment: Импортируйте класс